# How do I delete a ShareFile folder using the v3 ShareFile API?

Tags: sharefile

I am trying to delete a folder in ShareFile using the v3 ShareFile Rest API. I'm migrating from the older v1 API, and the migration documentation cites /sf/v3/Items/BulkDeletePermanently as the replacement, but I cannot get it to work.
Here is my bulk delete call and result:

```
POST https://[ShareFileHost].sharefile.com/sf/v3/Items/BulkDeletePermanently?ids=[folder id]
Returns:
   <code>BadRequest</code>
   <message>
      <lang>en-US</lang>
      <value>Missing Item Id</value>
   </message>
   <reason>BadRequest</reason>
```

I've tried this call with ids as a parameter and also with it as the Post QueryString and as PostData.

I also tried the DELETE with /sf/v3/Items.  Here is my call and the result:

```
DELETE https://[ShareFileHost].sharefile.com/sf/v3/Items([folder id])
Returns:

       <code>Forbidden</code>
       <message>
          <lang>en-US</lang>
          <value>Authorization failed: Item.You are not authorized to perform this operation.</value>
       </message>
       <reason>NotAuthorized</reason>
```

I verified with this call that my user has delete capability for the folder I'm trying to delete.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this.  When looking at permissions, I was looking at my subfolder.  The permissions needed to be on the parent folder.  I created a parent folder and gave my user delete permissions.  I then added a subfolder to it, and I was able to delete it using the DELETE with /sf/v3/Items.

Answer (score 0):

Example Permanently delete multiple items:

```
curl -X POST https://[ShareFileHost].sharefile.com/sf/v3/Items/BulkDeletePermanently
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
   -d "[\"id1\", \"id2\"]"
```

Example Delete Multiple Items (deletePermanently=true):

```
curl -X POST https://[ShareFileHost].sharefile.com/sf/v3/Items(parentid)/BulkDelete?forcesync=false&deletePermanently=true
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
   -d "[\"id1\", \"id2\"]"
```

> Where parentid is the ID of the parent folder; id1, id2 the ID of the
> items or folders

Response 204 No Content.

[API Ref](https://api.sharefile.com/docs/resource?name=Items)